# How to get data from get method

Tags: python, django

How to send title value in get method?

### getBooksDetails.html

```
    <a href="getBookDetails" style="text-decoration: none">
    <h4 class="overflow title" title="{{ book.title.upper }}">{{ book.title.upper }}</h4>
    </a>
```

### urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^index', 'views.index'),
    (r'getBookDetails', 'views.getBookDetails'),
)
```

I am trying to print value of title in this method just to confirm value is coming or not. Can someone please help me, how to send and get values in GET method.

### views.py

```
def getBookDetails(request):
    print request.GET // how to get title value here from get method
    return render_to_response('getBookDetails.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send data in the `URL`:

for example say we have an url like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/hi?id="bye"
```

You can obtain the data in `Django` from two ways:

```
request.GET['id']
```

or

```
request.GET.get('id', 'default value')
```

Comment: can u please explain how to send data in url?

Comment: The data being sent in the URL in this example is `?id="bye"`. Just by hitting this URL you're making `id` available in `request.GET`.

Answer (score 1):

A better, more search engine friendly way might be to use [keyword arguments](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#named-groups) in your URL, and have a [slug on your book object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify).

**getBooksDetails.html**

```
<a href="getBookDetails" style="text-decoration: none">
<a href="{% url 'book' book.slug %}>{{ book.title.upper }}</a>
</a>
```

**slug attribute on Book model**

```
from django.utils.text import slugify

class Book(Model):
    ...
    slug = slugify(self.title)
    ...
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       (r'^index', 'views.index'),
                       (r'getBookDetails/(?P<slug>\w+/', 'views.getBookDetails'),
)
```

And you can access the title-slug in your view either by using **kwargs if you're using class based views, or by adding `slug=None` to your view definition if you're using function based views.